# Flink: Convert a retracting SQL to an appending SQL, using only SQL, to feed a temporal table

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, stream-processing, apache-calcite, flink-sql

I am providing a Flink SQL interface to users, so I can't really use the Table or Java/Scala interface. Everything needs to be specified in SQL. I can parse comments in the SQL files though, and add specified ad hoc lower level API instructions.

How can one user could convert, say:

```
SELECT b, AVG(a) "average" FROM source_data GROUP BY b

name: average_source_data_retracting
  b STRING
  average NUMERIC
```

-which is retracting values- to a form that would append them. This appending form could have the following schema:

```
name: average_source_data_appending
  flag BOOLEAN <-- indicating an accumulate or retract message
  b STRING
  average NUMERIC
```

Aka sort of having the [RetractStreamTableSink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/table/sinks/RetractStreamTableSink.html) equivalent to the AppendStreamTableSink, but without it being a sink.

All this to enable the use of average_source_data_appending to create a [Temporal table](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/temporal_tables.html) (filtering  retract messages), but this kind of table only accepts append-only source tables.

I have considered using windows ([as talked about here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/streaming/dynamic_tables.html#update-and-append-queries)), but I'd like the updates to the temporal table to be instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please disregard this question, apparently the Temporal Table Functions can accept tables which are (to me) retracting.

Something to the effect of:

```
SELECT b, AVG(a) "average", MAX(proctime) max_proctime FROM source_data GROUP BY b
```

Can accepted as a Temporal Table Function with b as a key, and max_proctime as the time attribute. I guess the MAX(proctime) somehow makes it think new lines are emitted, when they are only overwritten? I think I need more time understanding this.

EDIT:

Digging through the source code, we find that Temporal Table Functions seem to accept retracting definitions, but only if it is under processing time:

[Temporal**ProcessTime**JoinOperator.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-table/flink-table-runtime-blink/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/operators/join/temporal/TemporalProcessTimeJoinOperator.java#L95):

```
@Override
public void processElement2(StreamRecord<BaseRow> element) throws Exception {
    if (BaseRowUtil.isAccumulateMsg(element.getValue())) {
        rightState.update(element.getValue());
        registerProcessingCleanupTimer();
    } else {
        rightState.clear();
        cleanupLastTimer();
    }
}
```

[Temporal**RowTime**JoinOperator.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-table/flink-table-runtime-blink/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/table/runtime/operators/join/temporal/TemporalRowTimeJoinOperator.java#L171):

```
@Override
public void processElement2(StreamRecord<BaseRow> element) throws Exception {
    ...
    checkNotRetraction(row);
    ...
}
private void checkNotRetraction(BaseRow row) {
    if (BaseRowUtil.isRetractMsg(row)) {
        String className = getClass().getSimpleName();
        throw new IllegalStateException(
            "Retractions are not supported by " + className +
                ". If this can happen it should be validated during planning!");
    }
}
```

This is undocumented; I don't know if this is permanent, and if the documentation will be updated.